# facial recognition using php

Tags: php, opencv, face-recognition

I'm trying to write a facial recognition algorithm using PHP?

I can do facial detection using OpenCV.
My goal is to come up with a way to take two faces and compare them to generate a percentage match.

I was going to have a user login then upload a photo of their face.  Then compare that image withe a couple of images of that user and be able to generate a percentage match.

I'm not expecting someone just to write this for me but maybe point me in the right direction.

Is there a openCV project that will do A to B face detection.

My idea was using openCV to detect facial features them to plot those features.  Is there a way to compare two coordinates to get a percentage using PHP?

Comment: [read a bit](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html)  btw, how do you plan to couple opencv (c++/python) to php ? (this part sounds very painful to me)

Comment: There is a face detect extension for PHP there are instructions online for compiling Facedetect for PHP.  http://www.xarg.org/project/php-facedetect/
There is code for facial detection that uses a process called haar cascade.
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html

Comment: yea, that might work. looks a bit outdated, though (using opencv's arcane c-api, which is no more . also note, that it can't read the newer lbp-cascades, which are a bit less precise, but much faster)

Answer (score 6):

Face recognition is a rather complex procedure, and doing it with PHP would be suboptimal.

I am looking for a similar solution, and have found this: [Web based interface for face detection with OpenCV](http://opencv-code.com/projects/web-based-interface-for-face-detection-with-opencv/). The idea is to use a compiled opencv-based program and call it from the PHP code. Fast and convenient.

Comment: Untested, but [one guy claims to have done it](https://github.com/mauricesvay/php-facedetection) :-)